# Split large file with awk, syntax error with regex

Tags: unix, awk

Got a large file with lots of xml doc's concatenated together.

Trying to split them with the following command;

```
awk '/<\?xml/{g++} { print $0 > "ipg130101-"g".txt"}' ipg130101.xml
```

But keep getting the error back;

```
 context is
/<\?xml/{g++} { print $0 > >>>  "ipg130101-"g <<< ".txt"}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Works well with GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 5.1.2)

Comment: Hmm, reckon it's a Mac OS X problem? having trouble getting csplit to work properly too

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use explicitly [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) instead of [nawk](/questions/tagged/nawk) (the latter is the default one on MAc Os X).

So finally :

```
gawk '/<\?xml/{g++} { print $0 > "ipg130101-"g".txt"}' ipg130101.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, looks like mac doesn't like it unless you put the filename as a variable first.

[Splitting a file using AWK on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980325/splitting-a-file-using-awk-on-mac-os-x)

```
awk '/<\?xml/{g++} {filename = "ipg130101-"g".txt"; print >filename}' ipg130101.xml
```

Comment: You can also surround it with parentheses (`print >("..."g".txt")`)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this statement:

```
print $0 > "ipg130101-"g".txt"
```

is ambiguous. It can mean:

```
(print $0 > "ipg130101-" g); ".txt"
```

or

```
(print $0 > "ipg130101-"); g ".txt"
```

or any other variation. For portability you MUST parenthesize whatever's on the right side of output redirection, i.e. explicitly write:

```
print $0 > ("ipg130101-"g".txt")
```

You don't need the $0, by the way, this would work fine:

```
print > ("ipg130101-"g".txt")
```

Comment: Darn it, Ed.  Everything I want to answer, you answer first, and better.  +1.