# extract some lines according to one field using bash scripting

Tags: bash

Please I need your help to get the below result file from file1, the file1 is so huge, and I want according to the first column ( Field 1) to extract each part in a file. Thanks in advance.

**File 1 :**
1111 3 4 5 7
1111 2 4 6 8
1111 1 5 9 3
1112 4 6 8 9
1112 6 8 7 7
1113 6 6 6 6
1113 7 7 7 7
...

**The result**
we get all the files according to the first field, in the brief file the result should be 3 files (file_1111, file_1112 and file_1113) as below:
***file_1111***
1111 3 4 5 7
1111 2 4 6 8
1111 1 5 9 3

***file_1112***
1112 4 6 8 9
1112 6 8 7 7

***file_1113***
1113 6 6 6 6
1113 7 7 7 7

best regards,

H.R

Answer (score 2):

Give this tested version a try:

```
awk '{print>>"file_" $1;}' File_1
```

By default `awk` splits the line containing spaces in fields `$1` `$2` etc.

This one-liner command writes each line in the file associated to current line's first field: `$1`.

The test:

```
$ cat File_1
1111 3 4 5 7
1111 2 4 6 8
1111 1 5 9 3
1112 4 6 8 9
1112 6 8 7 7
1113 6 6 6 6
1113 7 7 7 7

$ awk '{print>>"file_" $1;}' File_1

$ ls
File_1  file_1111  file_1112  file_1113
$ cat file_1111
1111 3 4 5 7
1111 2 4 6 8
1111 1 5 9 3
$ cat file_1112
1112 4 6 8 9
1112 6 8 7 7
$ cat file_1113
1113 6 6 6 6
1113 7 7 7 7
```

Pure bash script would probably run many processes in a loop and I believe it should be slower than one `awk` command.

--edited-- It does not matter if File_1 is sorted or not. It will do the trick.

Comment: Both this and the script solution may benefit from a file extension (e.g. `"file_" $1 ".txt";`) A good solution regardless.

Comment: You should be using `>`, not `>>` for the output redirection (this is awk, not shell - the semantics are different) and you need to parenthesize any expression on the right side of output redirection or the behavior is undefined and so will do what you expect only in some awks. You do not need the trailing semi-colon. So the correct script would be `awk '{print>("file_" $1)}' File_1` unless your file is non-trivial and you are using an awk that doesn't internally manage open files (gawk does) and then you will need `awk '$1!=prev{close(out); out="file_" $1; prev=$1} {print > out}' File_1`

Comment: @EdMorton thank you,first note that the tests were really executed so the solution works like a charm! I am going to test all this information. I have access to a debian squeezie for the tests and `mawk`. There is no `gawk` on the box. My main source is [Awk -A Tutorial and Introduction - by Bruce Barnett - The Grymoire!](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: @EdMorton Remark1 `>` is truncating the output files if they already exist. I used `>>` intentionnaly.

Comment: @EdMorton Remark 2 on `> expression`: this expression on the right side should return a string, there is nothing mentioning the use of `(` `)` in [awk - The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

Comment: @EdMorton Rermark 3 on semi-colon: true, but I prefer to keep using them.

Comment: @EdMorton Remark 4: I understand that using the `close` function is safer because each process as a limited number of open file descriptor allowed, rigth?

Comment: @Jayjargot Youre welcome, I know the script would produce the expected output given the posted sample input but that is the starting point for identifying a solution, not the end point. My comments were addressing what else needs to happen beyond that to make this a robust, portable, idiomatic solution.

Comment: Remark 1 - I highly doubt the OP wants the result of this op to append to existing files rather than overwrite them (e.g. if they run the tool a couple of times you don't really think they want it to keep appending to the output files do you?). In my experience that's something that, if desired, would be written as an explicit requirement not the behavior expected by default.

Comment: Remark 2 by definition you will not find undefined behavior defined in a spec, hence the term "undefined behavior". You won't find a statement that unparenthesized ternary expressions that start with a condition cause undefined behavior when used in a print statement either but they do. Google, however, is your friend.

Comment: Remark 3 - OK, it's not the worst thing you could do. Just a few extra characters here and there...

Comment: Remark 4 - correct. gawk manages the number of concurrently open files for you but other awks don't so using the explicit close() makes the script portable.

Comment: Going back to Remark 2 for a second - in case you're not convinced it's a real issue, there's an example of someone being bitten by not parenthesizing the right side of their output redirection in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20225919/1745001).

Comment: @EdMorton I think I learnt things today :) he! this last source is also from you! ;) I understand that `awk` parser is not enough accurately specified in the standard, that is why `(` and `)` are needed.

Comment: Yeah, I know it included my answer but it was the first thing I found when I googled and it does show the problem occurring in the wild which is the important thing. I'm sure there's some document out there somewhere that goes into the gory details - finding that is left as an exercise :-).

Answer (score 1):

If the data is sorted the way it is shown, shell can do it pretty well.

```
while read FileField DataFields || [ "$FileField" ] ;do
  echo "$FileField $DataFields" >> "file_$FileField"
done < "$yourInputFile"
```

If the data is not sorted as shown, the awk answer will likely be faster for large data sets.

... although The file field seems pretty pointless in the new files.  You could probably get away with `echo "$DataFields" >> "file_$FileField"`

Comment: I like it. I like it even more with an extension. If your `read` supports `-r` that is a worthwhile addition.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin A `read` without `-r` ? :-) http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `-r` _might_ speed it some, but the results should still be the same with the specified data set... I'm just trying to keep it "as simple as possible, but no simpler."

Comment: I tested both this solution and the (@Jay jargot) Awk solution on an old Linux machine.  For inputs I used a million-line sorted file and a million-line unsorted file.  For the sorted file this solution took 36 seconds, and the Awk solution took 0.5 (!) seconds.  For the unsorted file this solution took 36 seconds (no change, as expected) and the Awk solution took 14 seconds.  I was surprised by both the speed of Awk on the sorted file, and the huge slowdown on the unsorted file.  Bash performed rather better than I expected, but it clearly is not the right tool for a job like this.

Comment: @pjh all shell implementations are not created equally.  Bash is horribly slow compared to busybox ash for most basic use cases, especially when LANG is set to anything other than C.  I've seen 80-100x (times not percent) improvement just by changing the shebang and setting LANG to C.  FWIW, the 2.x version of bash commonly runs 4-8x faster than the current version.  IIRC, my prior testing found this method to be faster than awk for files up to  around 1000 lines, after that awk quickly wins.

Comment: @technosaurus, thanks for the information.  I guess that Awk is slower for smaller files because of the costs associated with running a subprocess.  Note that the OP explicitly referred to "huge" files, and tagged the question (only) with 'bash'.  I wasn't aware that Bash got so much slower after version 2 (which I don't think I have ever used).  I wonder what caused it?

Comment: @pjh That's exactly right.  Its not just awk... sed, grep, cut, tr, etc... all require roughly the same startup time.  That is a big reason why the old hotplug scripts were slow - they had to be Posix, so calls to sed/grep/awk/cut/tr couldn't be replaced with shell builtins.  Rewriting them to use busybox ash builtins actually got me significantly faster boot times than udev.  The main Posix limitation was the lack of certain substring maniplulations like: `${parameter/replace/with}`  As to bash getting slow since 2.x, FWIW they did add a lot of new functionality especially in 4.x.